How to Enable Drag-and-Drop to Rearrange Widgets in a QGridLayout in PyQt6?
I have implemented a drag and drop functionality to rearrange widgets in a QHBoxLayout. Below is the code:
from PyQt6.QtCore import QMimeData, Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QToolButton, QWidget, QGridLayout


class DragButton(QToolButton):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec(Qt.DropAction.MoveAction)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.blayout = QHBoxLayout()
        for l in ["A", "B", "C", "D"]:
            btn = DragButton(parent=self, text=l)
            self.blayout.addWidget(btn)

        self.setLayout(self.blayout)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()


    def dropEvent(self, e):
        pos = e.position()
        widget = e.source()

        self.blayout.removeWidget(widget)


        for n in range(self.blayout.count()):
            # Get the widget at each index in turn.
            w = self.blayout.itemAt(n).widget()
        
            if pos.x() < w.x() + w.size().height() // 2:
                # We didn't drag past this widget.
                # insert to the top of it.
                break
        else:
            # We aren't on the left hand side of any widget,
            # so we're at the end. Increment 1 to insert after.
            n += 1

        self.blayout.insertWidget(n, widget)

        e.accept()

app = QApplication([])
w = Window()
w.show()

app.exec()

I need to be able to save and store the re-arrangement in a dictionary. Because of this I thought it would be easier to arrange the layout in QGridLayout, since it's easier to retrieve and update a widget's position within a grid.
This is the code I have implemented:
from PyQt6.QtCore import QMimeData, Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QToolButton, QWidget

class DragButton(QToolButton):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec(Qt.DropAction.MoveAction)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.glayout = QGridLayout()
        for i, l in enumerate(["A", "B", "C", "D"]):
            btn = DragButton(parent=self, text=l)
            self.glayout.addWidget(btn, i, 0)  # Add buttons to column 0, different rows

        self.setLayout(self.glayout)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        pos = e.position().toPoint()  # Convert the position to a QPoint
        widget = e.source()

        # Get the original position
        for i in range(self.glayout.count()):
            w = self.glayout.itemAt(i).widget()
            if w == widget:
                original_row = i
                break

        self.glayout.removeWidget(widget)

        # Determine the new row based on drop position
        for n in range(self.glayout.count()):
            w = self.glayout.itemAt(n).widget()
            if pos.y() < w.y() + w.size().height() // 2:
                break
        else:
            n += 1

        # Shift widgets if necessary
        if n > original_row:
            for i in range(original_row, n):
                self.glayout.addWidget(self.glayout.itemAt(i).widget(), i, 0)
        else:
            for i in range(n, original_row):
                self.glayout.addWidget(self.glayout.itemAt(i).widget(), i + 1, 0)

        self.glayout.addWidget(widget, n, 0)

        e.accept()

app = QApplication([])
w = Window()
w.show()

app.exec()


The code kinda works but a lot of the times, the widget is just completely removed from the grid. Any ideas on how to implement this? or should I stick with a QHBoxLayout?

The problem is based on the fact that you believe that itemAt() respects the row/column order, but that is a wrong assumption. In fact, if you just print out the text of the buttons using the itemAt() after reordering, you will not get the same order that is shown visually. Why using a dict would change behavior? If you're worried about getting the indexes in the wrong order, then just iterate the keys using sorted(). If that doesn't work out for you, please clarify the usage of the dict, as I'm under the impression you're having an XY problem.

So basically, this tool buttons will be custom widgets a user will be able to add. I want to give him the option to customize the order of this buttons. And I want to save the arrangement so that when the user opens the gui again the buttons are arranged as he last left them. Which is why I think saving their index in a dictionary would work best, to load the arrangement at a later date. But if there’s a simpler way please let me know. Thanks!

I already explained it: saving the arrangement (the order) won't be affected by using a dictionary, if done appropriately, in a linear layout. Even assuming that the ordering is unsorted at reading (eg. {2: 'A', 0: 'C', 1: 'D', 3: 'B'}) you just need to sort it when recreating/reinserting those widgets. If that's not the way you're saving the insertion order, then, as said, please update your question clarifying that. Besides, unless you need further implementation (eg. "skipping" positions, so by adding spacers for empty slots in the layout), there's little point in using a dictionary.

Oh you are correct! Apologies. I meant to say, I wanted to use a grid layout because I felt it would be easier to manage the widget's position since I can associate the column number with a key in a dictionary.

Using QGridLayout is simpler, at least for some usages, because it doesn't really care about the item ordering. In fact, that's one of its benefits as it's one of its drawbacks: each "cell" in its grid could be used by more than widgets at the same time (for instance, you could place two widget in the same row and column). Its implementation, though, has some drawbacks (most importantly, the row and column count is *always increased but never decreased, even after destroying items occupying them). Just use your box layout implementation, only with appropriate referencing for its ordering.
